# undefined method `ncbi_ref_seq' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Generator has_many:results
Result belongs_to:generator

I want to have a page whereby i can view all the generators and the results.

## For example :This is from my generator/index.html

[image]

## this is from result/index.html

[image]

what i want to have is to combine them together and view all the data.[image]

right now this is what i've changed but i get the error message undefined method for ncbi_ref_seq. ( ncbi_ref_seq is an attribute belonging to the class Result )

## GeneratorController.rb

```
def index
    @generators = Generator.all(:include => [:results])
  end
```

## Generator/index.html.erb

```
 <tbody>
     <% @generators.each do |generator| %>
     <tr>
        <td><%= generator.primer_length %></td>
        <td><%= generator.choice %></td>
        <td><%= generator.random_primer_generated %></td>
        <td><%= generator.c_primer %></td>
        <td><%= generator.results.ncbi_ref_seq %></td>
    </tr>
     <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a generator has many results. When you take generator.results it returns an Active Record Collection, so there would be several records of Results, so you can't just extra a ncbi_ref_seq.

Either you have to loop through generator.results and output each ncbi_ref_seq like so

```
<% for result in generator.results %>
  <%= result.ncbi_ref_seq %>
<% end %>
```

Or a generator has_one result.

Comment: Hi Althhaf : appreciate your help. But in my generator/index view , i'm loading the the code <% @generators.each do |generator| %> and after that i have a <tr> . If i were to add the code u wrote , where should i place them ? i once tried them and it gives me error too ( each is undefined method or something )

Comment: Sorry I made a blunder in my code. I edited it. Replace this line in your code <td><%= generator.results.ncbi_ref_seq %></td> with what I have put.

Comment: Well the good news is that there is no error anymore but i'm getting empty data. The data are saved but the page are not showing any data.

Comment: Does your Result table have a generator_id. And when you create your Result is it assigned to a certain generator. You can check this by going to the rails console, just look at the output of Result.find(1) and see if it has a generator_id column. And look at the outputs of Generator.find(1).results and see if it has the data that you wanted.

Comment: yes i have them. t.index generator_id .In my Result controller, 
`def create`
   `@result = Result.new(result_params)`
   ` @result.generate_result(result_params)`
   ` @result.save` 

When i type Result.find(1) it tells me generator_id = nil. Is this why i get empty ? What causes this ? Generator.find(1).results desn't print any output

Comment: Yes this is the problem. When you are creating your result it is being saved as an individual entity and not linked back to a specific generator id.

Comment: ic...How should i fix it ? i mean now that i know is the Result create problem, how should i fix them

Comment: and i thought the association would help me linked them :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33448/discussion-between-bc2-and-althaf-hamez)